# How to capture photos using different exposure on single shot?

Tags: android-camerax

I need to implement some functionality like photo bracketing. I did lot off research to achieve this, but unable to find out solution. I am using camerax library to capture image. there is a requirement to capture image with multiple exposure values(photo bracketing). I found out some way like new

> Camera2Config.Extender(configBuilder).setCaptureRequestOption(
>   CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION, exposure);

But unable to use this using current version def camerax_version = "1.0.0-beta01" also can not find any possible alternative to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters#setExposureCompensation(int) using camerax. Please if you get a chance for this please help me to take out from this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With the newest released CameraX 1.0.0-beta01, you can do this by using `Camera2Interop.Extender(configBuilder).setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION, EXPO_TIME)`

Please check this out: https://groups.google.com/a/android.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/camerax-developers/_eronN-ITT4

Answer (score 0):

check the class Camera2Interop in beta release. let me know if it works